# Scala using Java libraries, taking advantage of lambda expressions support in Java 8

Tags: scala, lambda, javafx, java-8, javafx-8

According to:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#lambda-expressions-in-gui-applications

Previously:

```
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
});
```

Now, we can:

```
btn.setOnAction(
  event -> System.out.println("Hello World!")
);
```

---

Now, I try to do that in Scala when using a Java library.

I'm using JavaFX (which is included by default in Java 1.8 SE).
Try:

```
chart.setOnMouseClicked( (e: MouseEvent) => println("Noice") )
```

However, I get:

```
Error:(204, 46) type mismatch;
 found   : javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent => Unit
 required: javafx.event.EventHandler[_ >: javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent]
    chart.setOnMouseClicked( (e: MouseEvent) => println("Noice") )
                                             ^
```

The old style works fine:

```
chart.setOnMouseClicked( new EventHandler[MouseEvent] {
  override def handle(event: MouseEvent): Unit = println("NOT NOICE")
} )
```

**I set the project language level to Java 8 in IntelliJ, I'm using Scala 2.11.1, and Java from Oracle version 1.8.0_05**

What am I missing here? or is it simply not possible to pass a lambda expression from Scala to Java the same way it is done in the mentioned example?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For scala versions 2.12 onward support comes out of the box.

#### State for pre-2.12:

Lambdas was introduced in java **language** and has a little in common with scala functions. They're compiled down to a [different bytecode](http://www.takipioncode.com/2014/01/16/compiling-lambda-expressions-scala-vs-java-8/), has different hierarchy (scala functions were here long before and apparently java designers have chosen clean room implementation without compatibility with scala).

Currently support is pretty much limited and **what you're trying to do is not possible** (out of the box):

> The Scala 2.11 series targets Java 6, with (evolving) experimental
> support for Java 8. In 2.11, Java 8 support is mostly limited to
> reading Java 8 bytecode and parsing Java 8 source. We will be
> expanding Scala's (experimental) Java 8 support and interop throughout
> the 2.11 series. - See more at:
> https://typesafe.com/blog/scala-211-has-arrived#sthash.ukr4FSpU.dpuf

There is [ongoing efforts](https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat) to resolve this problem

See also [discussion on scala roadmap to support java 8 functions](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-internals/bdmNxpM0PnI/I0FLkAou2GMJ).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there is only experimental support for Java 8

Comment: btw, you have been replying to my questions for maybe 3 days straight... I have just noticed that it is you again !

Comment: @Spacemonkey "stalking scala users circa 2011" ;-)

Comment: I was just checking your profile here and on linkedin.. I stalk you back !

Comment: Scala 2.12 will default target Java 8, but current road map says it won't be out until January 2016.

Comment: @jordan3 thanks ! always nice to hear about new features

Answer (score 8):

One way to achieve this is using **implicit transformations** what you need to do is to create a new Object that handles all this transformations, something like this:

```
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent
import javafx.event.EventHandler

object FXEvent2HandlerImplicits{
  implicit def mouseEvent2EventHandler(event:(MouseEvent)=>Unit) = new EventHandler[MouseEvent]{
    override def handle(dEvent:MouseEvent):Unit = event(dEvent)
  }
}
```

Then just import it in any file that you may need the transformation:

```
import FXEvent2HandlerImplicits._   
//From now on within scope you can now call events like Java8 Lambdas
chart.setOnMouseClicked( (e: MouseEvent) => println("Noice") )
```

This is just Syntactic sugar to archive the same thing in a more elegant way