# Passing function in Scala

Tags: java, scala, generics, java-8

Since Java 8 I can pass intead of

```
xyz.foreach(e -> System.out.println(e));
```

I can do the following

```
xyz.foreach(System.out::println)
```

I have seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31927500/is-it-possible-to-use-a-java-8-method-reference-in-scala) about how method references work, but the problem is the following:

> Error:(16, 63) ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
>
> both method toJson in object IanesJsonHelper of type (source: IanesServer)String
>
> and  method toJson in object IanesJsonHelper of type (success: Boolean)String
>
> match expected type Function[?,String]
>
> ```
>  val json = IanesJsonHelper.toJson(array,IanesJsonHelper.toJson _)
>
>                                                         ^
> ```

I do have 3 functions with the name "toJSON"

```
def toJson(id: Int): String
```

and

```
 def toJson(success: Boolean): String
```

and

```
 def toJson(source: IanesServer): String
```

The last one is the right one.

The function I was calling in the error message above is:

```
def toJson[T](source: Array[T], toJson: Function[T, String]): String
```

This is the relevant code:

```
 val array = new Array[IanesServer](1)
 array(0) = new IanesServer(1, "http://localhost:4567/", "Test")
 val json = IanesJsonHelper.toJson(array,IanesJsonHelper.toJson)
```

I do not get what my mistake is:

1. The array is of type IanesServer
2. T in the calling method should be IanesServer (Array[IanesServer] -> Array[T]
3. Because of 2. the T in the function must be the same as the T in the array, therefore has to be Function[IanesServer,String] -> Function[T,String]

Can someone please be aso kind as to point out the mistake? At the moment I strongly disagree, that the function is [?,String]. Any ideas?

Answer:
Thanks for the quick answer, here is what I chose:

```
 IanesJsonHelper.toJson[IanesServer](array,IanesJsonHelper.toJson)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def toJson[T](source: Array[T], toJson: Function[T, String]): String
```

You expected the compiler to infer `toJson` to be of type `Function[IanesServer, String]` because `source` is of type `Array[IanerServer]` - and therefore `T` equals `IanesServer`.

Unfortunately, the scala compiler is not that smart. There are two ways you can help the compiler here:

1. State the types explicitly

   `IanesJsonHelper.toJson[IanesServer](array, IanesJsonHelper.toJson _)`
2. Split the parameters into two parameter lists:

   ```
   def toJson[T](source: Array[T])(toJson: Function[T, String]): String

   IanesJsonHelper.toJson(array)(IanesJsonHelper.toJson)
   ```

When you have two parameter lists, the arguments passed to the first list will tell the compiler how to bind `T`, and the compiler will use those bindings for the remaining lists.

Here's another shorter example:

```
// doesn't compile - the compiler doesn't realize `_` is an Int and therefore doesn't know about the `+` operator
def map[A, B](xs: List[A], f: A => B) = ???
map(List(1,2,3), _ + 1)  

//compiles fine
def map[A, B](xs: List[A])(f: A => B) = ???
map(List(1,2,3))(_ + 1)
```

---

This behavior may seem unfortunate, but there's a reason for it.

Scala, unlike Java or C#, uses all arguments in a function's parameter list to calculate their LUB (least upper bound) and use that to infer the function's generic type parameters.

For example:

```
scala> def f[A](x: A, y: A): A = x
f: [A](x: A, y: A)A

scala> f(Some(1), None)
res0: Option[Int] = Some(1)
```

Here, scala used **both** arguments (of types `Some[Int]` and `None`) to infer the type of `A` (`Option[Int]` - the LUB). And this is why scala needs you to tell it which overload of `toJson` you're referring to.

C#, on the other hand, [wouldn't allow this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jeyNeA).

> Compilation error (line 17, col 3): The type arguments for method 'Program.F(T, T)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

One last note: LUBing is awesome but also presents its [disadvantages](http://eed3si9n.com/stricter-scala-with-ynolub).

Comment: That's very bad, that the Scala compiler is not that smart. enough. The thing is, that (2) is not working (IntelliJ complains, that no method has that siigneture).
I am using " IanesJsonHelper.toJson[IanesServer](array,IanesJsonHelper.toJson)" now. Thanks a lot!

PS: Thanks for editing your post so many times :) Did help to make things clearer (no sarcasm, honestly)

Comment: @Reisi007 I know, right? This was surprising for me too, especially coming from a C# background where this would compile. Despite this small quirk, I'd still pick scala's type inference over C#'s any day.

Comment: I am coming from Java and there is no problem at all.. ( I guess, not tested). I am just getting used to Scala. Thanks for your quick answer anyway. Very appriciated :D

Comment: @Reisi007 Upon further reflection, I realized there's a reason *why* the compiler behaves this way. I've updated my post, hope it helps :)