# tidyr::spread() with plain Scala and Spark (rows to columns)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, transformation

my prototype (written in R with the packages [dplyr](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) and [tidyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/index.html)) is hitting a wall in terms of computational complexity - even on my powerfull working station. Therefore, I want to port the code to [Spark](https://spark.apache.org/) using Scala.

I looked up all [transformations](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#actions), [actions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#actions), [functions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) (SparkSQL) and [column operations](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column) (also SparkSQL) and found all function equivalents except the one for the `tidyr::spread()` function, available in R.

`df %>% tidyr::spread(key = COL_KEY , value = COL_VAL)` basically spreads a key-value pair across multiple columns. E.g. the table

```
COL_KEY | COL_VAL
-----------------
A       | 1
B       | 1
A       | 2
```

will be transformed to by

```
A       | B
------------
1       | 0
0       | 1
2       | 1
```

In case there is no "out-of-the-box"-solution available: Could you point me in the right direction? Maybe a user defined function?

I'm free which Spark (and Scala) version to choose (therefore I'd go for the latest, `2.0.0`).

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31927500/is-it-possible-to-use-a-java-8-style-method-references-in-scala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out-of-the-box but requires a shuffle:

```
df
  // A dummy unique key to perform grouping
  .withColumn("_id", monotonically_increasing_id)
  .groupBy("_id")
  .pivot("COL_KEY")
  .agg(first("COL_VAL"))
  .drop("_id")

// +----+----+
// |   A|   B|
// +----+----+
// |   1|null|
// |null|   1|
// |   2|null|
// +----+----+
```

You can optionally follow it with `.na.fill(0)`.

Manually without shuffle:

```
//  Find distinct keys
val keys = df.select($"COL_KEY").as[String].distinct.collect.sorted

// Create column expressions for each key
val exprs =  keys.map(key => 
  when($"COL_KEY" === key, $"COL_VAL").otherwise(lit(0)).alias(key)
)

df.select(exprs: _*)

// +---+---+
// |  A|  B|
// +---+---+
// |  1|  0|
// |  0|  1|
// |  2|  0|
// +---+---+
```

Comment: In case somebody tries this out: Dont' forget to import lit and when using `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lit, when}` (second option)