# How to translate the Java double colon operator (::) to Scala?

Tags: java, scala, lambda, camunda, scala-java-interop

I want to use [camunda-bpm-assert-scenario](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-assert-scenario/blob/master/example/src/test/java/org/camunda/bpm/scenario/examples/insuranceapplication/InsuranceApplicationProcessTest.java) in my *ScalaTests*.

There I have this code with `receiveTask::receive`:

```
when(documentRequest.waitsAtReceiveTask("ReceiveTaskWaitForDocuments")).thenReturn((receiveTask) -> {
  receiveTask.defer("P1DT1M", receiveTask::receive);
});
```

According to answer in [Is it possible to use a Java 8 style method references in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31935669/2750966) I can translate this quite easily to:

```
receiveTask.defer("P1D", receiveTask.receive _)
```

But this gives me:

```
Error:(84, 45) type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: org.camunda.bpm.scenario.defer.Deferred
       receiveTask.defer("P1D", receiveTask.receive _)
```

This is the `receive` function:

```
void receive();
```

And here is the expected interface:

```
public interface Deferred {
  void execute() throws Exception;
}
```

How can I achieve this in Scala?
This is not a duplicate of [Is it possible to use a Java 8 style method references in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31927500/is-it-possible-to-use-a-java-8-style-method-references-in-scala), there is no solution to "Error:(84, 45) type mismatch;
..."

Comment: Are you on scala 2.12+?
Can't check right now but `receiveTask.defer("P1D", e => receiveTask.receive(e))` shuld work. Also when it comes to Java interop you can just write `receiveTask.defer("P1D", new Deferred { override void execute ... })` and then ask IDE for suggestions how to make it less verbose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20001866/2750966), I could solve it to:

```
receiveTask.defer("P1D", new Deferred{
         def execute(): Unit = receiveTask.receive()
       })
```

Intellij proposed then to convert it to a *Single Abstract Method*:

```
receiveTask.defer("P1D", () => receiveTask.receive())
```

The problem was that `receive` had also an overloaded function that takes a parameter.